# How does code formatter work in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to format code on my blog like here
https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/
But it won't work... I'm editing post in html mode and still nothing.

```
[code lang="java"]
pubilic class something() {

}
[/code]
```

and I'm getting this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/installation/) plugin into your WordPress site?

If you do have the plugin installed, then they are aware of [one scenario](http://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/faq/) where the code will still not appear formatted:

> **The code is just being displayed raw. It isn't being converted into a code box or anything.** What's wrong? Make sure your theme's *footer.php* file has `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` somewhere inside of it, otherwise the plugin won't be able to do it's thing.

Comment: @Evelan: Added some info from the FAQ page about a situation just like yours. Ensure the template you are using actually allows the plugin to load up correctly.